# Image import in Astro and in Storybook are not of the same type

Tags: reactjs, storybook, astrojs

I'm using React in my Astro project. In a React file I import an image:

```
import logoNormal from "../../../images/logo/logo.png'
```

Then `logoNormal` will have a different type depending on the context: in Storybook, it will be a string with the path to the image, so I could render the image like this:

```
<img src={logNormal} alt=""/>
```

However, when in Astro, the import will be of type ImageMetadata, so to render it I would have to do something like:

```
<img src={logoNormal.src} alt=""/>
```

How should I deal with this in order to have both Astro project working and Storybook? I could change the structure of the component, and import the image outside of it as one solution, but is there a way to solve this while still importing the image inside the React component?